SSL stream crashes when a connection is closing
I have a TLS client based on ASIO. The simplified code is roughly as follows:
(Note: All socket operations are protected by mutex, and all ASIO asynchronous callbacks are executed in the same separate threads.)
std::mutex socket_op_lock;
ssl::stream<tcp::socket> ssl_socket;

Connect() {
    ssl_socket.next_layer().async_connect(on_connect);
}

on_connect(const asio::error_code& error) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    if (error) {
        CloseSocket();
    }
    else {
        ssl_socket.async_handshake(on_handshake);
    }
}

on_handshake(const asio::error_code& error) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    if (error) {
        CloseSocket();
    }
    else {
        Receive();
    }
}

Receive() {
    // called internal, already locked
    async_read(ssl_socket, ..., on_read);
}

on_read() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    if (error) {
        CloseSocket();
    }
    else {
        Receive();
    }
}

Disconnect() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    CloseSocket();
}

CloseSocket() {
    // called internal, already locked
    ssl_socket.next_layer().shutdown();
    ssl_socket.next_layer().close();
}

The problem occurs when the connection is closing. Since the ssl::stream shutdown might be blocking, I directly close the underlying TCP connection. However, I encountered the following occasional crashes on Android/iOS:
0  MyApp  asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::start_op(int, int, asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::descriptor_state*&, asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool) + 108
1  MyApp  asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::start_op(int, int, asio::detail::kqueue_reactor::descriptor_state*&, asio::detail::reactor_op*, bool, bool) + 100
2  MyApp  void asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::async_receive<asio::mutable_buffers_1, asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&> > >(asio::detail::reactive_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, asio::mutable_buffers_1 const&, int, asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&> >&) + 384
3  MyApp  asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&> >::operator()(std::__1::error_code, unsigned long, int) + 900
4  MyApp  asio::detail::reactive_socket_send_op<asio::const_buffers_1, asio::detail::write_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::mutable_buffer, asio::mutable_buffer const*, asio::detail::transfer_all_t, asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::handshake_op, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&> > > >::do_complete(void*, asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, std::__1::error_code const&, unsigned long) + 228
5  MyApp  asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, std::__1::error_code const&) + 692
6  MyApp  asio::detail::scheduler::run(std::__1::error_code&) + 188
7  MyApp  MyApp::NetworkIoThread::CustomLoop() + 44
8  MyApp  MyApp::OMMsgThread::Run() + 96
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_start + 136

So I guessed that after closing the underlying TCP connection, some operations in ssl::stream might still be triggered because the ssl::stream shutdown was not explicitly invoked, which led to the crashes. I then added the SSL layer shutdown process, and the code became like this:
Disconnect() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    ssl_socket.async_shutdown(on_shutdown);
}

on_shutdown() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> socket_op_lock;
    CloseSocket();
}

After making this change, there were more crashes on the iOS platform, with the following stack trace:
0  MyApp  CRYPTO_memcmp + 76
1  MyApp  aes_gcm_tls_cipher + 624
2  MyApp  aes_gcm_cipher + 96
3  MyApp  EVP_Cipher + 64
4  MyApp  tls1_enc + 2748
5  MyApp  ssl3_get_record + 3220
6  MyApp  ssl3_read_bytes + 744
7  MyApp  ssl3_read_internal + 128
8  MyApp  ssl3_read + 52
9  MyApp  ssl_read_internal + 340
10 MyApp  SSL_read + 96
11 MyApp  asio::ssl::detail::engine::perform(int (asio::ssl::detail::engine::*)(void*, unsigned long), void*, unsigned long, std::__1::error_code&, unsigned long*) + 96
12 MyApp  asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::read_op<asio::mutable_buffers_1>, asio::detail::read_dynbuf_op<asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >, asio::basic_streambuf_ref<std::__1::allocator<char> >, asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&, unsigned long), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> const&> > >::operator()(std::__1::error_code, unsigned long, int) + 92
13 MyApp  asio::detail::reactive_socket_recv_op<asio::mutable_buffers_1, asio::ssl::detail::io_op<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp>, asio::ssl::detail::read_op<asio::mutable_buffers_1>, asio::detail::read_dynbuf_op<asio::ssl::stream<asio::basic_stream_socket<asio::ip::tcp> >, asio::basic_streambuf_ref<std::__1::allocator<char> >, asio::detail::transfer_at_least_t, std::__1::__bind<void (MyApp::MyTcpClient::*)(std::__1::error_code const&, unsigned long), std::__1::shared_ptr<MyApp::MyTcpClient>, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<1> const&, std::__1::placeholders::__ph<2> const&> > >::do_complete(void*, asio::detail::scheduler_operation*, std::__1::error_code const&, unsigned long) + 196
14 MyApp  asio::detail::scheduler::do_run_one(asio::detail::conditionally_enabled_mutex::scoped_lock&, asio::detail::scheduler_thread_info&, std::__1::error_code const&) + 692
15 MyApp  asio::detail::scheduler::run(std::__1::error_code&) + 188
16 MyApp  MyApp::NetworkIoThread::CustomLoop() + 44
17 MyApp  MyApp::OMMsgThread::Run() + 96
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib  __pthread_start + 148

However, it is strange that there are no issues on the Android platform.
Why is this happening, and how do I solve this problem?

Perhaps you should build with debugging symbols so you know the line numbers?  And perhaps Valgrind will give insight into the problem?

I was using the debug version, so the function name should be correct; And the crash is happened in asio/openssl, so i think the line numbers is not the key to solve the problem;
